# Split a Pandas Dataframe into multiple smaller dataframes based on empty rows

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file with a format like this:

```
Header 1, Header 2, Header 3
''          ''        ''
value 1,  value2,   value 3
value 1,  value2,   value 3
value 1,  value2,   value 3
''          ''        ''
value 1,  value 2,   value 3
value 1,  value 2,   value 3
value 1,  value 2,   value 3
 ''          ''        ''
```

I can read it into a pandas dataframe but the segments surrounded by empty rows (denoted by `''`) need to be each processed individually. What would be the simplest way to divide them into smaller dataframes based off of them being between empty rows? I have quite a few of these segments to go through.

Would it be easier to divide them into smaller dataframes or would removing the segment from the original dataframe after processing it be even easier?

**EDIT:**

IanS's answer was correct but in my case some of my files had simply no quotes in empty rows so the type was not a string. I modified his answer a little and this worked for them:

```
df['counter'] = (df['Header 1'].isnull()).cumsum()
df = df[df['Header 1'].isnull() == False]  # remove empty rows
df.groupby('counter').apply(lambda df: df.iloc[0])
```

Comment: The simplest would be to add a counter that increments each time it encounters an empty row. You can then get your individual dataframes via `df.groupby('counter')`. If you are interested I can write an answer.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try writing it on my end but if you write yours I shall accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to add a counter that increments each time it encounters an empty row. You can then get your individual dataframes via `groupby`.

```
df['counter'] = (df['Header1'] == "''").cumsum()
df = df[df['Header1'] != "''"]  # remove empty rows
df.groupby('counter').apply(lambda df: df.iloc[0])
```

The last line applies your processing function to each dataframe separately (I just put a dummy example).

Note that the exact condition testing for empty rows (here `df['Header1'] == "''"`) should be adapted to your exact situation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can find empty rows by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), create counter `series` by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by it and in loop you get small `DataFrames`:

```
print df['Header 1'].str.contains("''").cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    3
Name: Header 1, dtype: int32

for idx, group in df.groupby(df['Header 1'].str.contains("''").cumsum()):
    print idx
    print group[1:]
1
  Header 1  Header 2    Header 3
1  value 1    value2     value 3
2  value 1    value2     value 3
3  value 1    value2     value 3
2
  Header 1   Header 2    Header 3
5  value 1    value 2     value 3
6  value 1    value 2     value 3
7  value 1    value 2     value 3
3
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Header 1,  Header 2,  Header 3]
Index: []
```

If you want, you can create dictionary of `DataFrames`:

```
dfs = {}
for idx, group in df.groupby(df['Header 1'].str.contains("''").cumsum()):
    dfs.update({idx:group[1:]})
```